# Doxygen Latex, customize header and footer

Tags: latex, doxygen

Hi I'm using doxygen to create documentation of my code. I'm specifically interested in generating a PDF, so I generate the Latex first and then convert it to PDF.

My problem is that I would like to have a custom header and footer, like these:
[image]

[image]

So, for the header, a title, a logo (png image) and a blue line.
For the footer only a blue line and the page indication.

I've seen that when I generate the documentation I can pass header.tex and footer.tex files, just to customize the header and footer, but I can't figure out how to write .tex files to get the result I want.

In case it is not possible or too complicated, it would be enough for me to be able to generate my own output without header and footer, so that I can then add them with a pdf editor after the conversion.

Can anyone help me customize or remove Latex header and footer?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Doxygen also has the possibility of LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET so you can overrule / redefine /create your own commands. Doxygen also uses the fancyhdr package.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that there are various ways to upload custom .tex files or latex stylesheets. My question was not whether or not it is possible to upload these, but I needed help writing these files. I have never used Latex, and it seems to me very complex to learn in the initial phase, I was looking for someone who has been using latex for years and who could help me write those 10 lines to modify or remove the header and footer, without having to studying Latex for a week just for this little thing.